# regex to match all 3 words in a paragraph or a multiline command output

Tags: regex

Need a regex to match 3 words in this output (syslogd, Mutex and devc-conaux )

Thu Dec 22 09:24:55.359 UTC
  Jid       Pid Tid            Name State   TimeInState    Blocked-on
  433    163845   3         syslogd Mutex 9522:45:38:0462  163845-07 #1
  433    163845   7         syslogd Reply 10618:23:23:0504   12298  devc-conaux
  433    163845   8         syslogd Mutex 10618:23:21:0802  163845-07 #1
65548     12300   1             ksh Reply 15269:15:10:0850   12298  devc-conaux

I am a beginner, pls help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework to me, but I'll bite:

```
/(syslogd|Mutex|devc-conaux)/g
```